# Scapy sniff cannot 'sniff' any packets

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, scapy, sniffing

I have a problem with sniff function from scapy library. For some unknown reasons, it cannot sniff any receiving packets anymore. I don't define any interface so I assume it should be able to sniff all incoming packets and it worked just fine for a week until yesterday. I tried to re-install the library and disable all the extensions on VSCode to see if it could help and yet nothing has solved the problem. I appreciate all the help!

```
from scapy.all import sniff

sniff(prn=lambda x:x.show(), timeout=5)
```

Comment: I think the problem may come from agr "timeout=5", just delete it and try again

Comment: Originally, I don't use timeout argument, however it would just keep on sniffing forever and when I stopped the sniffing, it would print out '<Sniffed: TCP:0 UDP:0 ICMP:0 Other:0>, basically means nothing is received throughout the period even if I visit a bunch of websites

Comment: Have you try to run the command as sudo permission ?

Comment: And one more thing, maybe you miss the "count" agr to define number of packets to capture. It should be like sniff(prn=xxxx, count = 1), if you set count to 0 it means infinity

Comment: I'm using Powershell so unsure about how to run it with sudo command yet, however, about using 'count' argument even if I set 'count' to be 1, it would still run infinitely since no packet is captured for it to stop.

Comment: I tried opening VSCode using 'Run as Administrator and ran the code, and still no luck by far